# Angularjs Wizard hide wz-step

Tags: angularjs, wizard

How I can hide a **wz-step** depending on a value of a previous step?

My HTML:

```html
<wizard on-finish="submit()" hide-indicators="true" currentStep="data"> 
 <wz-step wz-title="onestep">
  <p>Show two step?</p>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="data.question" class="md-primary">
  <md-radio-button ng-value="1"> Yes </md-radio-button>
  <md-radio-button ng-value="0"> No </md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <md-button type="submit" wz-next>NEXT</md-button>
 </wz-step>
 <wz-step wz-title="twostep" ng-show="data.question == 1">
    //Two step, show if data.question = 1
 </wz-step>
 <wz-step wz-title="finalstep">
  <md-button type="submit" wz-next class="md-raised">Submit</md-button>
 </wz-step>
</wizard>
```

My js:
scope.data = {
        question: 0,
    };

I tried with ng-show and ng-if, with ng-show always shown and with ng-if never does :(

I hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ng-hide when the user clicks on the next step.

For example:

```
 <div ng-hide = "show">
          <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
 </div>

<input type="button" ng-click="MyFunction" value="Next">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.show = false;
$scope.MyFunction = function(){
    if($scope.test == null){ // or undefined...
          $scope.show = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for your response, but what I want is to hide a **wz-step** , "skip" the wz-step if choose question = no

Comment: you could use wz-disabled ="true/false", the logic as the same like the above example. Later I'm going to update the code, but try.

Comment: Hello friend, I tried to do with wz-disabled, but not recognize my "scope.show"

Comment: Hello Edith, yes, i have it.
My wz-step:

**<wz-step wz-title="awards" wz-disabled="{{show}}">**

Thank you!

Comment: That's great!! Take care =)

Answer (score 0):

Just read the documentation missing
https://github.com/angular-wizard/angular-wizard
Section **Wizard Dynamic Steps**
Thanks **Edith Capistran**